# PSD to HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm converting a psd file to HTML and CSS and I'm having trouble with the background. The background of the design has a layer mask which is black. That's what I'm having nightmares with.

Any ideas on how to implement that in HTML and CSS?

Comment: Please provide more details: post your design so we can see what you are trying to accomplish. Also tell us what you have already tried. Also please accept answers to your questions.

Comment: There could be many reason. Without providing specific input can't help you out. You should post your question with some details. How can we understand what your psd is and what you have converted?

Answer (score 2):

Try simply:

```
body { background:#000; }
```